# multiple authentications in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10

we have multiple local IIS (asp.net) websites in our local server that can access via static IP from Internet. Each website has own authentication for itself(forms authentication).
We need a master website that our static IP redirect to it, and after authentication(forms) can access to another sites by link(after second authentication for each site that opened).

I tried virtual directory and got error for WEBCONFIG, after that use applications under master website, also got error because of multiple authentication(without master authentication works perfectly).

Is there a way to have multi form authentication for that?
Thank a lot.

Comment: The description looks rather messy. Can you migrate all sites to a Single Sign On solution to eliminate all those unnecessary hurdles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use firewall accounting for it. When an IP receive by firewall, redirect to a login page that use AD for authenticating.